# Como passar props através do react router

Tags: react

Como passar props através do

```
<Link to=''>
```

Preciso pegar a informação em outro componente

Comment: Já deu uma lida sobre o WithRouter? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um objeto invés de uma string no 'to' e assim você consegue enviar props via a propriedade state

```js
<Link to={{
  path: '/login'
  state: { someData: [] }
}} />
```